# Positioning a container without it moving when space is changed

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position one container in a specific place - how can I do this and make it stay to its proportionate place even when I zoom in or out the screen?

HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

<div id="huvud">

</div>

<div id="nav-yttre">
    <div id="nav-mitten">
        <ul id="nav-inre">
            <li><a href="index.html">HEM</a></li>
            <li><a href="om_oss.html">OM OSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="blogg.html">BLOGG</a></li>
            <li><a href="marken.html">M&Auml;RKEN</a></li>      
            <li><a href="hitta_hit.html">HITTA HIT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="main">

    <p>Hem</p>

</div>

<div id="right">
    <p>This container</p>
</div>

<div id="fot">
    <div id="adress">
        <p id="rub">BES&Ouml;KSADRESS</p>
        <p>V&auml;gen 1, 12345 Stockholm</p>
    </div>

    <div id="kontakt">
        <p id="rub">KONTAKTA OSS</p>
        <p>Telefon: 08-123 45 67</p>
        <p>Mail: info@hej.se</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tider">
        <p id="rub">&Ouml;PPETTIDER</p>
        <p>Vardagar: 10-19<br>L&ouml;rdag: 10-17<br>S&ouml;ndag: 11-16</p>  
    </div>

    <div id="design">
        <p>Webbplatsen &auml;r gjord av MD</a></p>
    </div>

</div>


</body>
```

CSS:

```
/* Header */

#huvud{
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header{
display: block;
}

/* Meny */

#nav-yttre{
width: 1000px;
height: 35px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: url("Rusty-bar2.jpg");
}

#nav-mitten{
display: table;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
}

#nav-inre{
display: table-row;
list-style: none;
font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
font-size: 25px;
}

#nav-inre li{
display: table-cell;
}

#nav-inre li a{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
color: #eeeeee;
}

#nav-inre li #here{
color: #221f20;
}

#nav-inre li a:hover{
color: #221f20;
}

/* Main */

#main{
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 500px;
}

#fadein { 
margin: 10px auto;
position:relative; 
width:281px; 
height:500px; 
padding: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#fadein img { 
position:absolute; 
}

/* Right */

#right{
position: absolute;
left: 1450px;
top: 200px;
background-color: #221f20;
height: 300px;
width: 200px;
}

#right p{
color: white;
}

/* Fot */

#fot{
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-top: solid #221f20 1px;
text-align: center;
clear: both;
}

#adress{
width: 334px;
float: left;
}

#kontakt{
width: 333px;
float: left;
}

#tider{
width: 333px;
float: right;
}

#design{
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
clear: both;
text-align: center;
background-image: url(rusty-bar-small.jpg);
}

#design p{
color: #eeeeee;
font-weight: bold;
}

#design a{
color: #eeeeee;
}

#design a:hover{
color: #221f20;
}

#rub{
font-weight: bold;
}

/* Allmänt */

p{
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #221f20;
font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nvsodsfs/1/

And result: http://jsfiddle.net/nvsodsfs/1/embedded/result/

Comment: What's the container element ID and under what circumstance is it moving?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's the div called "right". It's moving when I zoom in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a div which is centered and 1000px wide: `#huvud`.

Place the div in `#huvud`:

```
<div id="huvud">
    <div id="right">
        <p>This container</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Make `#huvud` `display: relative` so that position absolute children position themselves in relation to it. It now looks like this:

```
#huvud {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Make `#right` `left: 100%` so it is forced outside of its new parent and then give it a left margin as desired:

```
#right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 200px;
    background-color: #221f20;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 100px; /*need more?*/
}
```

### Complete Example

All other content has been removed for simplicity.

Make the example full-screen and see it remain fixed in place on zoom-in/out

```css
/* Header */

#huvud {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
/* Right */

#right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 200px;
  background-color: #221f20;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
Other content removed for simplicity - the div is this way >>>>>> 

<div id="huvud">
  <div id="right">
    <p>This container</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this will work but you could set its min width to your chosen size and set Max width the same.

If you want it to stay in the same place use % for sizes and it will shrink better without moving.

Also you should set some sizes for your body to contain all this

Answer (score 0):

I would just wrap all the centered content with a div (with a position:relative) and then you can position the container with right:0. Depending on the width of the wrapper, it will be less or further right.